How does TikZ draw a smooth cycle?
To draw a smooth cycle with TikZ, one might use code such as this (lifred from page 349 of pgfmanual.pdf):
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw plot[smooth cycle,tension=1] coordinates {(0,0) (1,0) (2,1) (1,2)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

But exactly what is TikZ/pgf actually doing? How does it draw the curve? Obviously, the curve is drawn so as to pass through the points with the given coordinates. But what else does it do to get the entire curve? Is it using some kind of Bezier curve and, if so, with what control points?

Have a look at the manual for hobby. Although that's concerned with providing a different algorithm, it explains also how PGF does it, if I remember correctly.

@cfr: I see a detailed explanaation of the hobby algorithmin Section 4 of the manual for that TikZ package, but no explanation of the native TikZ algorithm itself. But thanks for the pointer tohobby`, which for my purposes may produce nicer curves does plain TikZ. (But I'd still like to see an explanation of the TikZ algorithm!)

Apologies. I must be misremembering.

You could ask barbara if there has been anything in TUGboat?

Let's draw the smooth cycle, but include the control points using the following code (adapted from the TikZ/PGF manual, Section 50.4, Path Replacing Decorations):
\tikzset{
    show curve controls/.style={decoration={show path construction, curveto code={
        \draw[blue, densely dotted] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) --(\tikzinputsegmentsupporta)
            node [at end, red, solid, draw, circle, inner sep=.5pt]{};
        \draw[blue, densely dotted] (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast)
            node [at start, red, solid, draw, circle, inner sep=.5pt]{};
    }}, decorate}
}

This style plots the control points as well as the curve. For example,
\draw [postaction=show curve controls, thick]
    (0,2) .. controls (2.5,1.5) and (0.5,0.5) .. (3,0);

Produces the image:

If we apply this style to smooth cycle:
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);\coordinate (B) at (1,0);\coordinate (C) at (2,1);\coordinate (D) at (1,2);
\draw[ultra thin, gray!50](0,0)grid(2,2);
    \draw[postaction=show curve controls] plot[smooth cycle, tension=1] coordinates {(A) (B) (C) (D)};
\draw[red] (A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

we get the following picture:

So we see the smooth cycle is created with four curves, each with two control points. The first control point, together with the initial point of the segment, forms a line parallel to the line connecting the previous point and the following point (to the initial point). Similarly the second control point together with the terminal point forms a line parallel to the line connecting the previous point and the following point (to the terminal point).
The distance of the control point to its respective point is the length of the segment connecting the previous and following points multiplied by a constant that equals tension*0.2775. The constant is chosen so that tension=1 corresponds to a circle if the four points are uniformly spaced. Thanks to @Andrew Stacey for clarifying the tension constant.

Here is the code to produce the above image. All control points are calculated in terms of the four given coordinates. Adjusting the constant \mytension changes the tension and the constant described above.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathreplacing, calc} 

\newcommand{\mytension}{1}

\tikzset{
    show curve controls/.style={decoration={show path construction, curveto code={
        \draw[blue, densely dotted] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) --(\tikzinputsegmentsupporta)
            node [at end, red, solid, draw, circle, inner sep=.5pt]{};
        \draw[blue, densely dotted] (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast)
            node [at start, red, solid, draw, circle, inner sep=.5pt]{};
    }}, decorate}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);\coordinate (B) at (1,0);\coordinate (C) at (2,1);\coordinate (D) at (1,2);
\draw[ultra thin, gray!50](0,0)grid(2,2);
    \draw[orange, ultra thick] let \p1=($(C)-(A)$), \p2=($(D)-(B)$) in (A)
        .. controls ($(A)+({atan2(-\y2,-\x2)}:{sqrt(\x2*\x2+\y2*\y2)*\mytension*.2775})$) and ($(B)+({atan2(-\y1,-\x1)}:{sqrt(\x1*\x1+\y1*\y1)*\mytension*.2775})$) .. (B)
        .. controls ($(B)+({atan2(\y1,\x1)}:{sqrt(\x1*\x1+\y1*\y1)*\mytension*.2775})$) and ($(C)+({atan2(-\y2,-\x2)}:{sqrt(\x2*\x2+\y2*\y2)*\mytension*.2775})$) .. (C)
        .. controls ($(C)+({atan2(\y2,\x2)}:{sqrt(\x2*\x2+\y2*\y2)*\mytension*.2775})$) and ($(D)+({atan2(\y1,\x1)}:{sqrt(\x1*\x1+\y1*\y1)*\mytension*.2775})$) .. (D)
        .. controls ($(D)+({atan2(-\y1,-\x1)}:{sqrt(\x1*\x1+\y1*\y1)*\mytension*.2775})$) and ($(A)+({atan2(\y2,\x2)}:{sqrt(\x2*\x2+\y2*\y2)*\mytension*.2775})$) .. cycle;
    \draw[postaction=show curve controls] plot[smooth cycle, tension=\mytension] coordinates {(A) (B) (C) (D)};
    \draw[red] (A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

As an example, here is what it looks like when the points are changed:
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);\coordinate (B) at (1,1);\coordinate (C) at (3,1);\coordinate (D) at (1,2);

with \mytension=2.


Just to add, the constant is almost exactly 3.6 as you surmise. It is, in fact, 1/0.2775 = 3.6036036036.... The maths is slightly simpler than you describe, but only because instead of dividing by 3.6.../tension then it multiplies by 0.2775*tension. The purpose of the funny numbers is so that tension=1 with four equally spaced points will result in a circle. The details are all in pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex.

PS I think this is a fabulous piece of deductive work, by the way.

@AndrewStacey: Thank you for the clarification. That makes perfect sense. I updated my code with the correct constant.

As far I can see, coordinates behave as the symmetrical Bezier nodes of Inkscape, i.e, with a  left and right control point at the same distance for each coordinate, and the tension option just set this distance.
So, if you draw a square, at tension=0 the lines ares not curved, since control points are just at the coordinates. When tension is >0, the control points move away from the coordinate forcing a smooth curve, so the square becomes a circle when tension is 1. With higher tensions the curvature is forced to become a peak (or a loop when is very high (> 4 or so), so control points overlap:


\documentclass[tikz,margin=1pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (.5,.5) circle (1.9em);
   \draw plot[smooth cycle,tension=0] coordinates {(0,0) (0,1) (1,1) (1,0)};
   \draw plot[smooth cycle,tension=1] coordinates {(0,0) (0,1) (1,1) (1,0)};
   \draw plot[smooth cycle,tension=2.7] coordinates {(0,0) (0,1) (1,1) (1,0)};
   \draw plot[smooth cycle,tension=5] coordinates {(0,0) (0,1) (1,1) (1,0)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



+1 Nice picture for a boat logo... lol
